# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am getting an error in my application when I want to upload an image with Multer. I already tried to change the name and the loading address but still did not achieve anything. Any ideas ?
[image]

This is the code:

```
const multer = require('multer');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname,'../views/upload'));
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now());
    }
})


var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})
```

Route:

```
router.post('/user/change/image', upload.single('image'), isAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{
    const file = req.file.image

    if(!file) {
        req.flash('error', 'Porfavor introduce un archivo valido')
    } else {
        res.send(file)
        res.redirect('/user')
    }
})
```

Form EJS:

```
            <div class="tarjetaedit col-sm-6">
                <form  method="POST" action="/user/change/image" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <legend class="legend">Imágen de perfil</legend>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Subir foto</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Thanks to all ! I really need to fix this <3

Comment: Already fix that ! But now i get the file without the format..

Comment: Already solved with path!